# How to plot recurrencies in R

Tags: r, plot, recurrence

How can I plot a recurrency in R.
Any solution with base plot, ggplot2, lattice, or a dedicated package is welcome.

For example:

Imagine I have these data:

```
mydata <- data.frame(t=1:10, Y=runif(10))

t         Y
1 0.3744869
2 0.6314202
3 0.3900789
4 0.6896278
5 0.6894134
6 0.5549006
7 0.4296244
8 0.4527201
9 0.3064433
10 0.5783539
```

I could transform it like this:

```
mydata2 <- data.frame(t=c(NA,mydata$t),Y=c(NA,mydata$Y),Y2=c(mydata$Y, NA))

 t         Y        Y2   
 NA        NA 0.9103703
 1 0.9103703 0.1426041
 2 0.1426041 0.4150476
 3 0.4150476 0.2109258
 4 0.2109258 0.4287504
 5 0.4287504 0.1326900
 6 0.1326900 0.4600964
 7 0.4600964 0.9429571
 8 0.9429571 0.7619739
 9 0.7619739 0.9329098
10 0.9329098        NA
```

(or similar methods, but I can have problems  with missing data)
And plot it

```
plot(Y2~Y, data=mydata2)
```

I guess I must use some grouping function such as ave or apply. But it's not an elegant solution, and if I have more columns it can become difficult to generalize the transformation.

For example

```
mydata3 <- data.frame(x=sample(10,100, replace=T),t=1:100, Y=2*runif(100)+1)
```

For every x (or combination of values on other columns) I want to plot `Y_{i+1} ~ Y_i,` on the same plot.

Other tools, such as Mathematica have functions to plot sequences directly.

Comment: Are you looking for the `lag` function?

Comment: lagging is what I did manually, but as I said I'm looking for something more direct that could work even with more columns (by groups).  And missing values won't produce the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, thoug not very beautiful:

For this sample data.

```
mydata <- data.frame(x=sample(4,25, replace=T),t=1:25, Y=2*runif(25)+1)

newdata <- mydata[order(mydata$x, mydata$t), ]
newdata$prev <- ave(newdata$Y, newdata$x, FUN=function(x) c(NA,head(x,-1)))
plot(Y~prev, data=newdata)
```

In this example you don't have rows for every t value, you would need to first generate NAs for missing values. But it's just a quick solution. In my real data I have many observations for each t.
lag.plot can plot recurrence plots but not within each subgroup.